# Append to existing CSV with headers

Tags: java, csv

I have a method that appends to a .csv file but the problem is that it adds a header row everytime as well. How can I append to the .csv correctly?

I am aware that adding to a List would do the job but this method is called in separate runs.

```
public static void writeToCSVFileAndSend(String facilityId, int candidateStockTakeContainersCount) throws IOException {

        FileWriter report = new FileWriter("/tmp/MonthlyExpectedComplianceSuggestions.csv", true);
        LocalDate today = java.time.LocalDate.now();
        String[] headers = { "Warehouse", "Expected Count for "+ today.getMonth().getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.ENGLISH)};
        Map<String, Integer> facilityExpectedMonthlyCountMap= new HashMap<String, Integer>() {
            {
                put(facilityId, candidateStockTakeContainersCount);
            }
        };
        try (CSVPrinter printer = new CSVPrinter(report, CSVFormat.DEFAULT
                .withHeader(headers))) {
            facilityExpectedMonthlyCountMap.forEach((a, b) -> {
                try {
                    printer.printRecord(a, b);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        }
}
```

Current Output

```
Warehouse,Expected Count for Dec
A,2147
Warehouse,Expected Count for Dec
B,0
```

Expected Output

```
Warehouse,Expected Count for Dec
A,2147
B,0
```

Comment: how are you calling method writeToCSVFileAndSend? Since your output shows 2 records, I guess you are calling writeToCSVFileAndSend for each pair of facilityId and candidateStockTakeContainersCount

If you are calling method twice, it will create CSVPrinter object at each call and add header to it

Comment: Yes I am calling the method multiple times, in multiple runs(over multiple days). I do understand why the header is being added each time, but is there a way to check if the header is present, we skip it?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid multiple headers, you should create object of CSVPrinter once and reuse it
Depending on how you are getting the data, you may split the function in two and pass CSVPrinter object around.

```
public static void writeToCSVFileAndSend() throws IOException
{

    File outputCSV = new File( "/tmp/MonthlyExpectedComplianceSuggestions.csv");
    LocalDate today = java.time.LocalDate.now();
    String[] headers = { "Warehouse", "Expected Count for "+ today.getMonth().getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.ENGLISH)};

   boolean headerRequired = true;
   if( outputCSV.exists()){
     headerRequired  = false;
   }
   
    
    CSVPrinter printer = null;
    if( headerRequired){
     printer  = new CSVPrinter(report, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader(headers));
    }
    else{
      printer = new CSVPrinter(report);
   }


    // Iterate through combination of facilityId and candidateStockTakeContainersCount and 
    // call print record
    Map<String, Integer> facilityExpectedMonthlyCountMap= new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    // fill in your data in map here

    facilityExpectedMonthlyCountMap.forEach((a, b) -> {
                try {
                    printer.printRecord(a, b);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });



}
```

Comment: I can't do that since this method is being called in different runs.

Comment: edited the code to handle the condition. If output csv exists, then CSVPrinter instance is created without headers.